# Disk Utility App on Mac cannot do FirstAid on my SD card

Tags: disk-utility, sd-card

While I was using my Olympus E-M5 mark 2, suddenly it shows me a message "card error". Thus I connect the SD card to my mac, which also shows a message "The Disk You Inserted Was Not Readable by This Computer". After researching how to fix a broken SD card, I decided to use the First Aid function on Disk Utility App on Mac to find the problem. However, that function also shows a message "First Aid process has failed. If possible back up the data on this volume. Click Done to continue." with the detailed message:

======================================================

"Running First Aid on “” (disk2s1)

Repairing file system.
Volume is already unmounted.
Performing fsck_msdos -y /dev/rdisk2s1
** /dev/rdisk2s1

Invalid BS_jmpBoot in boot block: 819fb0

File system check exit code is 8.
Restoring the original state found as unmounted.
File system verify or repair failed. : (-69845)

Operation failed…

==========================================

Please help me identify what the details say because I have no idea. Does it mean that my SD card of beyond repair and I cannot download 8GB of pictures on the card?

Comment: Do you have access to a Windows PC to try reading/repairing it on? The card is in a FAT volume format (probably FAT32, possibly ExFAT), and macOS's tools for dealing with that are limited. Windows tends to have better compatibility and tools for reading and repairing these formats.

Comment: Could you read the SMART status with DriveDX Demol? You can try a data recovery tool such as Data Rescue or Disk Warrior.